# Wordpress wp_options : "home" issue

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with my Wordpress SQL `wp_options` table.
The line "home" has disappeared.

I tried to reinsert it but it's impossible: `error because of the primary key`

[image: error message]

How can I do to reinsert it without any issues?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to insert that row *without*  the primary key `option_id` to avoid that problem. The index usually auto-increments and doesn't need to be set.

On the other hand, if `option_id` `2` still exists, you might want to use an `UPDATE` statement to fix it...